# Create a graph from a CSV file and render to browser with Django and the Pandas Python library

Tags: python, django, numpy, matplotlib, pandas

I'm learning how to use the Django framework for a work project that will allow users to load files in various formats (at the moment I am only dealing with CSV files), graph that data using [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), and display that data back to the user via a Django template. I haven't had any problems creating the graph in iPython, but have been struggling with getting it to an HTML Django template.

I've followed the following example from `matplotlib`:

```
# graph input file

from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

def graph(request):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    x = []
    y = []
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    for i in range(10):
        x.append(now)
        now += delta
        y.append(random.randint(0, 1000))
    ax.plot_date(x, y, '-')
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
    fig.autofmt_xdate()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

The above example works great and I can see it in a template, but that's just a graph with hard-coded values.

I've attempted to use `Pandas` because of its seemingly simplistic syntax and my attempts in Django are as follows:

```
# graph input file

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

def graph(request):
    data_df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/vut46744/Desktop/graphite_project/sampleCSV.csv")
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(dataArray)
    data_df.plot()
    response = HttpResponse( content_type = 'image/png')

    return response
```

In Django calling the `.plot()` displays the graph fine, but displays a blank page to the HTML template. I've also tried using Numpy's `genfromtxt()` and `loadtxt()`, but to no avail. Also, my Google searches have not been fruitful either.

Any help or suggestion would be great. If you know of a better alternative to Pandas then I am willing to try other options.

Comment: It would be a tremendous help if you showed the dependencies next time. I'm still trying to figure out which dependencies you used in order to get the right result.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried this yet, but I would attack it something like:

```
def graph(request):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    data_df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/vut46744/Desktop/graphite_project/sampleCSV.csv")
    data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_df)
    data_df.plot(ax=ax)
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

Comment: Your answer with a little modification did the trick. See code below. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh yes, I misnamed a variable :) Glad it helped!